# On the multiplication of the symmetric algebra monad

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory, definition, monads

In their paper "Generators and bases for algebras over a monad" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.10223.pdf) Zetzsche, Silva and Sammartino introduce the Symmetric algebra monad. It is an endofunctor in the category of vector spaces over a given field $k$ that sends a vector space to its symmetric algebra and a linear map to the unique algebra homomorphism obtained by the universal property of the symmetric algebra. They claim that this endofunctor is a monad where "multiplication flattens tensors over tensors in the usual way." What is meant by this quote? How is the multiplication of the symmetric algebra monad defined?

Comment: It means removing parentheses: $(x \otimes y \otimes \cdots) \otimes (z \otimes \cdots) \otimes \cdots = x \otimes y \otimes \cdots \otimes z \otimes \cdots \otimes \cdots$.